# Rich Text Box problem when reading a Rich Text Format

Tags: c#, visual-studio, winforms, exception, registry

I have a problem with my app. I made this for opening a file on double-click with my app:

```
public void ProcessText()
    {
        Path = Args[Args.Length - 1];
        System.Windows.Forms.RichTextBox TB = new System.Windows.Forms.RichTextBox();
        TB.Text = Path;
        ContentTextBox.Text = System.IO.File.ReadAllText(TB.Text);
        if (Args.Length == 1)
            ContentTextBox.Text = ET;
    }
```

I'm trying to open a file in my app using the registry and it works, but when I'm trying to read a rich text format it shows this:

> {\rtf1\ansi\ansicpg1252\deff0\nouicompat\deflang1033{\fonttbl{\f0\fnil\fcharset0 Segoe UI;}{\f1\fnil Segoe UI;}}
> {\colortbl ;\red255\green255\blue255;}
> {*\generator Riched20 10.0.19041}\viewkind4\uc1
> \pard\cf1\f0\fs18 gtfyrdetfyguhkiljoulhykgtjfrhdegsw\f1\par
> }

Whatever this means...

I'm trying to make it look like this:

"tgyhjumki,ujhytgrfghbnjmk"

I used the code from the Open File Dialog:

```
ContentTextBox.LoadFile(OFD.FileName);
```

This is what it ended up to look like:

```
public void ProcessText()
    {
        Path = Args[Args.Length - 1];
        System.Windows.Forms.RichTextBox TB = new System.Windows.Forms.RichTextBox();
        TB.Text = Path;
        ContentTextBox.LoadFile(TB.Text);
        if (Args.Length == 1)
            ContentTextBox.Text = ET;
    }
```

After I used this code it told me that there is an error: System.ArgumentException: 'File format is not valid.'

Please help me fix this without using the registry editor

Comment: The encoding in the test box is Windows Encoding 1252.  So to display properly you need a font that support 1252 encoding.

Comment: It doesn't let me change the font. I need a solution in the C# code

Comment: How did you create the file?

Comment: You need to set the RTF property, not the Text!! What you see it the raw RTF content, ie all sorts of commands in curlies..

Comment: System.ArgumentException: 'Illegal characters in path.' - That's what it shows me when I'm using Rtf instead of Text

Comment: @Andrei Zait, what is content for your current file? can you provide the file?  which line throws the exception you get?

Comment: @JackJJun-MSFT This one: ContentTextBox.LoadFile(TB.Text);

Answer (score 0, accepted):

I did some research and I found something: Firstly, yes I'm answering my own question but I do that for you to understand. The code I used is this:

```
    public void ProcessText()
    {
        Path = Args[Args.Length - 1];
        System.Windows.Forms.RichTextBox TB = new System.Windows.Forms.RichTextBox { Text = Path };
        try
        {
            ContentTextBox.LoadFile(Path);
        }
        catch
        {
            ContentTextBox.Text = System.IO.File.ReadAllText(TB.Text);
        }
        if (Args.Length == 1)
            ContentTextBox.Text = ET;
    }
```

This means that:

When I tried to use the simple text method for the rich text document, there was an error. The exception was thrown because there was no opened file of any format in the text editor, so I made it TRY the open text and when it fails, it tries something else, If none work, the text will be null. That's the solution.

Also thanks for your suggestion - they helped me figure out this problem.

Comment: Short:
Now when I open a simple text file it will SHOW a SIMPLE text file

Comment: And when I open a RICH TEXT FILE it will SHOW a RICH text file